# Radius of convergence and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}P_k(z)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum \limits_{n\geq 0}\begin{pmatrix} n+k\\k \end{pmatrix}z^n$

Tags: limits, functions, power-series

The radius of convergence of $P_k(z)=\sum \limits_{n\geq 0}\begin{pmatrix} n+k\\k \end{pmatrix}z^n$ should be $R=1$ if I'm correct. I am now trying to find $P(z)$:$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}P_k(z)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum \limits_{n\geq 0}\begin{pmatrix} n+k\\k \end{pmatrix}z^n$$ I have no idea how to go about this problem. Is there some identity for binomial coefficents that I'm missing?

Comment: $P_k(z)=(1-z)^{-k-1}$ when $|z|<1$.

Comment: How? :D Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Looks like you're using the binomial series.

Comment: Yes, I just use the generalised binomial series and simplify the binomials with negative entries. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases and in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Are you sure this is true? The equation in the Wikipedia article holds for a sum where we sum over $k$.

Comment: $$\binom{n+k}{n}=\binom{n+k}{k}$$ Can you see why? :)

Comment: Oh, dang it, you're right!

Comment: So, as $k\to \infty$, we have $P(z)=0$?

Comment: It depends on $z$. If $z=1/2$ say, it is $2^{k+1} \to \infty$.

Comment: Well, as $k\to \infty$, we have $P_k(z)\to \infty$ for $|z|<1$, right?

Comment: The radius of convergence is $R=1$.

Comment: What if $z=-1/2$ say? What if $z=0$?

Comment: For $z\in (-1,0)$ it converges to $0$, for $z\in (0,1)$ it diverges to $\infty$. And for $z=0$ it goes to $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!